# MS Access Form Not Showing Results

Tags: ms-access-2010

This is truly baffling.

I have a subform that is set up as a continuous form and receives data from a query.  Here is the SQL

```
SELECT Top 12 Tbl_Parent_ITN.ID, Tbl_Parent_ITN.ITN_Number, Tbl_Child_ITN.ITN, 
Tbl_Child_ITN.Parent_ITN_fk, Tbl_Scope_Rqmts.Completed, Tbl_Scope_Rqmts.Child_ITN_fk, 
Tbl_Lkup_Requirements.Requirement, Tbl_Lkup_Basis.Basis
   FROM Tbl_Parent_ITN INNER JOIN (Tbl_Lkup_Requirements 
     INNER JOIN (Tbl_Lkup_Basis INNER JOIN (Tbl_Child_ITN INNER JOIN Tbl_Scope_Rqmts 
       ON Tbl_Child_ITN.Id = Tbl_Scope_Rqmts.Child_ITN_fk) ON Tbl_Lkup_Basis.ID = Tbl_Scope_Rqmts.Basis_fk) 
        ON Tbl_Lkup_Requirements.ID = Tbl_Scope_Rqmts.Requirements_fk) 
         ON Tbl_Parent_ITN.ID = Tbl_Child_ITN.Parent_ITN_fk
           WHERE (((Tbl_Parent_ITN.ID)=[Forms]![Frm_Parent_ITN_Main]![parent_id]));
```

The criteria in the where clause of the SQL is passed based on the control in the form that precedes this form.  The value is the primary key of the parent table that joins with several child tables to get all of the data for the subform.

When I open the with one record that has children it works perfectly fine and the form populates with 12 records.  However, when I go run the same operation on the next parent record I don't get any results in view even though that parent has 4 child records.

What is really perplexing is that when I run the query independently from opening the form it gives me the exact results that I want based on that 2nd parent record.  Furthermore, if I change the subform to a datasheet I still don't get any records; however, I can see the results in the filters of the datasheet form if I select those column headers (but no records show in the form itself).  The properties of the subform are the exact same in both cases, so I can't understand what would cause the records to show in the 1st case but not the 2nd??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few suggestions:
1. Try to do a Me.Refresh to see what happens. 
2. Put a break point in the form's OnError event to see is there is something wrong.
3. Check if there is any other data source that may be locking any data that should be refreshed.
4. Verify that the no properties that define the parent-child relationship of the data is being changed during runtime.
5. Check if the parent record id gets refreshed on the OnCurrent event of the form.

Hope this helps,
FunkSoulBrother

Comment: thank you Funk!  Your ideas for 3 and 4 make me consider the fact that the Link Master Fields and Link Child Fields were set up based on the relation of the tables; however, I was using the previous form id value to filter the query (which basically allows me to accomplish what I want with the form unbound).  So when I removed the fields from these properties it worked correctly!!  Thank you.